# break to lable as default case in switch statment not behaving logically

Tags: java, control-flow

First thank you for reading. Also I'm very aware of how I can get this to work they way I want it to. I'm just experimenting and not getting expected results.
When I run this code I would expect that when I enter the letter X I would be asked 
to try again and re-attempt to enter the letter B. Well, I am. However The program will then break to the start: label and process based on the new value of input we got in the 
default case. If on my second attempt I enter the letter B, nothing gets executed in the 
switch statement. If you enter the letter B on your second try, the program will print that you entered B and then the program will terminate. Why is this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Help
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the letter B: ");
      char input = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
      start:
      switch(input)
      {
         case 'B':
            System.out.println("Nice Work!");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("Try again: ");
            input = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(input);
            break start;

      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labeled `break` statement is meant for *terminating* loops or the `switch` statement that are labeled with the corresponding label. It *does not* transfer control back to the label. Your `switch` statement is simply falling through to the end of program, as it should.

A labeled `break` would only be helpful if you had nested `switch` statements and needed to `break` out of the outer one from the inner one.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) for further information.

Comment: Thank you. Basically I was expecting it to behave as a C goto statement and that's clearly not whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use while cycle:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Help
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the letter B: ");
      while(true)
      { 
        char input = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
        switch(input)
        {
         case 'B':
            System.out.println("Nice Work!");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("Try again: ");
        }
      }

   }
}
```